# Moment js get seconds remained

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have a timestamp and I need to run my code 30 seconds before timestamp is reached.

`Logic`

1. Get current time
2. Get database timestamp
3. Run code 30 seconds before database timestamp

`sample code`

```
const now = moment(); // current time
const then = moment.unix(chainIds[i].timestamp); // returns: 2023-02-15T18:11:00+07:00
// run something (console log perhaps)
```

so based on my database timestamp my code has to be run at `18:10:30`

`actual code`

> Note: problem with this code is that its running even days after timestamp is passed.

```
const now = moment();
const then = moment.unix(chainIds[i].timestamp);
const delta = now.diff(then, 'seconds'); // get the seconds difference

var itstime = false;
if(moment.unix(delta).format("ss") <= 30){
    itstime = false;
} else {
    itstime = true;
}
```

I know I'm close to the solution but there is a bug that I can't figure it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a minimum value condition to make sure it won't run too far after the target. Here I'm giving it a 60 second buffer so that it will still run if the code isn't triggered exactly at 30 seconds, but you can adjust that to your needs.

```
var itstime = false;
var seconds = moment.unix(delta).format("ss");
if(seconds <= 30 && seconds >= -30){
    itstime = false;
} else {
    itstime = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a lot more simple

```
const now = moment();
const then = moment.unix(chainIds[i].timestamp);
const delta = now.diff(then, 'seconds');

var itstime = false;
if(delta < 30){
    itstime = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super sure but from what I understood, your difference is getting a second time, now.diff gets the result, see

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moment-js-moment-diff-function/

so I don´t think you need

```
moment.unix(delta).format("ss") <= 30
```

have you tried something like

```
const now = moment();
const then = moment().add('minutes', 1);
const delta = now.diff(then, 'seconds'); // get the seconds difference

var itstime = false;
if (delta <= 30) {
  itstime = false;
} else {
  itstime = true;
}
```